# How to select the last element of a JSON array in AWS Athena?

Tags: sql, json, amazon-athena, presto, trino

My database has a column that contains a JSON array like this:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES 
        ('1', JSON'[{ "name" : "foo" }, { "name" : "bar" }]'),
        ('2', JSON'[{ "name" : "fizz" }, { "name" : "buzz" }]'),
        ('3', JSON'[{ "name" : "hello" }, { "name" : "world" }]')
    ) AS t(id, my_array)
)
```

I want to select the `name` property from the last element in the array:

| result |
| --- |
| bar |
| buzz |
| world |

I can select the first element easily enough:

```sql
SELECT json_extract_scalar(my_array, '$[0].name') FROM dataset
```

These attempts did not work for the last element:

```sql
SELECT json_extract_scalar(my_array, '$[-1].name') FROM dataset

SELECT json_extract_scalar(my_array, '$[cardinality(json_parse(my_array)) - 1].name') FROM dataset

SELECT element_at(my_array, -1) FROM dataset
```

Note: I cannot make any assumptions about the length of the JSON array.

Comment: For Json array I think you need to use `json_array_length` instead of `cardinality`

Comment: @SyndRain - I can't figure out how to do it with `json_array_length`, but please post an answer if you figure it out! I updated the original question with a more complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to your answer.

1. `json_extract`/`json_extract_scalar` work with quite limited subset of JSON path queries so one way to achieve your goal is to cast to `array`. Few notes:

   - No need for `json_extract` you can cast `JSON` type directly, if column is of string type use `json_parse` before cast.
   - You can use `JSON` as target type, i.e. `array(json)` or `array(map(varchar, json))`, which can be useful in case of mixed content inside array/JSON object properties:

   ```
   SELECT element_at(CAST(my_array AS ARRAY(MAP(VARCHAR, JSON))), -1)['name']
   FROM dataset;
   ```
2. Trino, which should be the base for Athena since 3rd version has several advanced [functions to use with JSON path](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json-path-syntax-and-semantics) like `json_query` or `json_value`, which can be used in this case:

   ```
   SELECT json_value(json_format(my_array), 'lax $[last].name')
   FROM dataset;
   ```

Comment: Both solutions appear to work well. Any trade-offs to consider?

Comment: @srk Was glad to help! Not much that I know of, maybe one can be a bit more performant then the other but in general case I would argue that it should not be that noticable, so should be matter of style preference. Also the map one should fail if the key is not present in the map (as far as I remember)

Answer (score 1):

You can do so like this:

```
SELECT element_at(my_column, -1) 
FROM your_table_name;
```

More info:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/accessing-array-elements.html

Comment: This was helpful, but missing the important part of converting the JSON array to an array, since you cannot use `element_at` on a JSON array. I posted a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working:

1. Cast the JSON array to an array
2. Use `element_at` on the array

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES 
        ('1', JSON'[{ "name" : "foo" }, { "name" : "bar" }]'),
        ('2', JSON'[{ "name" : "fizz" }, { "name" : "buzz" }]'),
        ('3', JSON'[{ "name" : "hello" }, { "name" : "world" }]')
    ) AS t(id, my_array)
)

SELECT element_at(CAST(json_extract(my_array, '$') AS ARRAY(MAP(VARCHAR, VARCHAR))), -1)['name']
FROM dataset
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/searching-for-values.html